# C++ program behavior on pointers to integer array

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers

> Can anyone please explain why the loop only execute once!!

The for loop executes once and never reaches end of the programm
and if you've got some time to review my mistakes then please point out mistakes because i know this is not how it is done!!

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>

int* rotate(int* ar,int d,int n)
{
    int tmp[n];
    d = d%n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        tmp[i] = ar[(i+d)%n];
    }
    free(ar);
    return tmp;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *a;
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    a = rotate(arr,4,n);
    cout<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
         cout<<i<<endl;
         cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"End";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `free(ar);` is bad because something not allocated via `malloc()` family is passed. Using `malloc()` and `free()` in C++ is not a right way.

Comment: `free(ar);` for an array that wasn't allocated using `malloc()`?

Comment: @MikwCat yupp but do you know the reason of the for loop executing only once and not reaching end of the programm

Comment: why are you doing any of this to begin with? I suppose this is an exercise, but consider that there is `std::vector`/`std::array` and `std::rotate`, which can do the same in roughly 2-3 lines

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes i can do it with vector, but i'm just messing with pointer knowledge of mine!!

Comment: `int tmp[n];` Nooooooo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take it apart...

```
int* rotate(int* ar,int d,int n)
{
    int tmp[n];                     // 1
    d = d%n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        tmp[i] = ar[(i+d)%n];
    }
    free(ar);                       // 2
    return tmp;                     // 3
}
```

`int tmp[n];` is [not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). If you do not want to use `std::vector` the proper replacement would be a dynamically allocated array.

You call `free` with a pointer that was not allocated via `malloc`, which invokes undefined behavior. In C++ you shouldn't be using `free` and `malloc` at all, but rather `new` and `delete`. And also `new` and `delete` only for such exercise. Otherwise use smart pointers.

You [return a pointer to a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope?rq=1). The pointer is dangling and using it in main invokes undefined behavior.

You can't simply replace the static array `arr` in `main` with something else in the function. A function called `rotate` is not expected to create a new array or delete the one that was passed (also because like in your case it is just not possible).

There are different ways to fix your code. I choose to make `rotate` rotate the array "in-place". However, as you can see, the implementation actually uses an additional array of same size. I leave it to you to figure out how to change it to use less additional memory:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void rotate(int* ar,int d,int n)
{
    int* tmp = new int[n];
    d = d%n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        tmp[i] = ar[(i+d)%n];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        ar[i] = tmp[i];
    }                       
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    rotate(arr,4,n);
    cout<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
         cout<<i<<endl;
         cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"End";
    return 0;
}
```

This is how you can do the same using `std::rotate`:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    std::rotate(std::begin(arr),std::begin(arr)+4,std::end(arr));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
         std::cout << i << std::endl;
         std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"End";
}
```

... it even uses pointers ;)

Comment: Thanks for all this explanation....and yes a lot better code than this can be written...but my c++ knowledge is not to that point!!

Comment: @nish_13 don't you agree that the code that uses `std::rotate` is much simpler than the one with the handwritten algorithm?

Comment: yes i totally agree that it is simpler as well as efficient (the code you suggested). but i was just kind of exploring more on this ( the code i wrote )!!
And thanks for juggling with me like this : ) others don't even bother to answer